# Wordpress plugin that will preview and display my hyperlinks into RSS like feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, plug-in, hyperlink

I have a media page with Press releases about my website. As of now, they are all hyperlinks, I want to make it into a something similar to social media feed - where I will give the URL and it will show the preview automatically in a block within the feed.

Are there any plugins for this?

I tried to find the answer, but everything was about RSS or social media feed.
Thank you very much!